# PHP form - conditions for field

Tags: php

I need add two requirements.

- domain name must be without diacritics
- domain name must have a minimum 3 characters

This transfer into error message mentioned below (Error: Domain name can not be left empty.)

```
<form action="" method=post>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="domain_name" style="width:170px;"></td>
            <td>
                <select name="suffix" style="width:75px;">
                    <option value=".sk" align="left">.sk</option>
                </select>  
            </td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" id="popUpYes" name="check" value="Check"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>    

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['check'])) { 
        if (!empty($_POST['domain_name'])){
            $name_domain = trim($_POST['domain_name']).$_POST['suffix'];
            $response = @dns_get_record($name_domain, DNS_ALL);

            if(empty($response)){
                echo "<span style='color:red;'>Domain is free.</span>";
            }else{ 
                echo "<span style='color:red;'>Domain is registered.</span>";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "<span style='color:red;'>Error: Domain name can not be left empty.</span>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: These things you need to add? Did you try anything or you want us to make it for you?

Comment: if($name_domain.lenght<3)
{
echo "Domain name is less than 3";
}

and for diacritics you need to make a regular expression.

Comment: I need add two requirements for domain name - Domain name must have a minimum 3 characters and must be without diacritic. If domain have a diacritic or have a less as 3 characters reflect message in Error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['check'])) {

  if (!empty($_POST['domain_name'])){
     if (strlen ($_POST['domain_name']) > 3){
        if (preg_match ("/^\w+$/", $_POST['domain_name'] )){
           $name_domain = trim($_POST['domain_name']).$_POST['suffix'];
           $response = @dns_get_record($name_domain, DNS_ALL);
           if(empty($response)){
             echo "<span style='color:red;'>Domain is free.</span>";

           }else{ 
             echo "<span style='color:red;'>Domain is registered.</span>";
           }
        }
        else {
           echo "<span style='color:red;'>Error: Domain name characters must to be alphanumeric.</span>";
        }
    }
    else {
       echo "<span style='color:red;'>Error: Domain name must contain at least 3 characters.</span>";
    }
 }
 else {
    echo "<span style='color:red;'>Error: Domain name can not be left empty.</span>";
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: It´s working solutions. Very very thank you and I wish you have a nice day.

Comment: A bracket left. Updated. Don't forget to mark the answer as answered if it works. Thanks

Comment: Manolo, please I need these requirements in fields.

Without diacritic, allowed numbers and

domain-domain-.sk - bad
domain-domain.sk - ok
-domain-domain.sk - bad

Comment: I see your website msalsas.com and I contact you via your contact form and I'll give you a reward for your efforts..

Comment: It seems like you have not send the form, since I've not received anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(empty($response)){
     if(preg_match('/[^-_a-z0-9.]/iu', $_POST['domain_name'])){
     if(strlen(strpbrk($_POST['domain_name'], '.')) > 3) {
      echo "<span style='color:red;'>Domain is free.</span>";
}
}


     }
```